# Python Debugging in Vscode - make it similar to PyCharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn Python and if you look 5-7 minutes into this tutorial he's able to - in a very illustrative way - debug (or "follow") his code. I'm unable to replicate this in a similar way in Vscode.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akcEaEH91gI

Is it not able, or is it done in another way?

If you look at my screenshot. Nothing is added inside the script-console or the debugging console - as in `PyCharm`. Meanwhile, I get some data to the left but it's not as illustrative.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpguK.png

Not bashing Vscode, just trying to learn. :) Thanks

Comment: debugging starts at 8min, what spectacular feature are you missing in debugging this 4 line piece of python

Comment: @Duck Flightsson -Hi, how are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For the requirements you mentioned, please refer to the following:

1. **About viewing variables.**

   In VSCode, we can view the variables in the code in the following two places:

   1). "`VARIABLES`" on the left side of "`Side Bar`":

   [image]

   2). Right-click the mouse and click "`Run Current File in Ineractive Window`":

   [image]
2. **About "DEBUG CONSOLE"**.

   When we use the setting `"console":"internalConsole"` in "`launch.json`", the execution result of the code will be displayed in "`DEBUG CONSOLE`", and VSCode will output in "`integratedTerminal`" by default.

   [image]

In addition, since they are different software, we can't require them to be exactly the same in use. But if you encounter any usage and technical problems when using VSCode, please let us know.

More reference: [The use of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs).

Comment: Anyone interested in using `"internalConsole"` globally (it is per-debug-configuration currently) may want to upvote this feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18353